# Custom Keras metric return 'axis out of bounds' error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've built a multi-class, multi-label image classification network using Keras. There are 25 classes overall and each image has at least one class in it. I want to implement a custom accuracy metric which tells me how often the highest probability class is in the image (regular accuracy is less meaningful as the true positives are swamped by the true negatives).

I've built a simple function which generates the desired accuracy metric when I manually feed in y_true and y_pred. However when I try and insert this function into the model training process, it produces an error.

```
def customAcc(y_true, y_pred):
    classPreds = np.array([np.eye(numClasses)[x] for x in  np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)])
    correctPreds = y_true * classPreds
    return np.mean(np.sum(correctPreds, axis=1))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001), 
loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy', customAcc])
```

> AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

`y_pred` is 1D, it only has one possible axis. Remove `axis=1` from your `np.argmax` call.

---

### Walkthrough

The problem in this particular case is this line:

```py
classPreds = np.array([np.eye(numClasses)[x] for x in  np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)])
```

Specifically: `np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)`.
Your `y_pred` is a one-dimensional array - such as `[0.1, 0.2]` - and you're telling `np.argmax` to look for values across `axis=1` which doesn't exist unless you pass arrays with two or more dimensions - such as `[[0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4]]`.

An actionable example:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> num_classes = 25
>>> np.argmax([0.1, 0.5, 0.9]) # max value's index on 1D array
2
>>> np.argmax([0.1, 0.5, 0.9], axis=1) # max value's index on axis 1 of 1D array
AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

Had `y_pred` been a 2D array, the axis error wouldn't happen - but `np.argmax` would then return a list of indexes **instead of a scalar**, such as below:

```py
>>> np.argmax([
...     [0.1, 0.5, 0.9],
...     [0.9, 0.5, 0.1]
... ], axis=1)
array([2, 0], dtype=int64) # first array's max at index 2, second array's max at index 0
```

By taking away `axis=1` from `argmax`, you'll then get the correct, scalar index for the maximum value within `y_pred`.

Comment: to be clear, both y_pred and y_true and 2d matrices that are n (number of data points) by k (number of classes) and contain class probabilities and one-hot encoded classes respectively

Comment: That's curious, then. Could you edit your question posting the full stack trace of the error, if that's the case? From your original snippet, the only AxisError-prone line is the one I mentioned.